# Using a shell script as a virtual printer

Tags: shell-script, printing, cups

I have a shell script that takes a PDF file as an argument and prints it with additional printer specific options. How can I add this script as a virtual printer that can be selected from the GUI?

The shell script is a manual duplex script that takes a PDF file, prints even pages, gives a user prompt using zenity asking the user to flip the pages and then prints the odd pages.

My current workflow is:

1. File -> Print -> Save to file -> tmp.pdf
2. `my_duplex_script tmp.pdf`
3. `rm tmp.pdf`

Is there any way to make it as :

1. File -> Print -> my_script_as_virtual_printer

Note: This is on Linux mint 13 cinnamon. I have tried `gnome-manual-duplex` but it doesn't work for me.

---

The GUI dialog from which I can print to a PDF file
[image: Standard GTK print dialog]

`my_duplex_script`

```
#!/bin/bash

lp_args=
while getopts o: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        o)  lp_args="$lp_args -o $OPTARG" ;;
        \?) echo >&2 Invalid argument; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`

file=$1
page_count=$(pdfinfo "$file" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}')
is_odd=`expr $page_count % 2`

if [ $is_odd -eq 1 ]
then
    #outputting blank
    echo | lp -s -t "$file"-blank
fi

#printing even reversed
lp -s -o page-set=even -o outputorder=reverse $lp_args -t "$file"-even "$file"

if zenity --question --text="Flip and reinsert the entire stack when printing has finished." --ok-label="Proceed" --cancel-label="Cancel"
then
    #printing odd reversed
    lp -s -o page-set=odd -o outputorder=reverse $lp_args -t "$file"-odd "$file"
else
    echo >&2 User abort
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried this but there is a tool called [`tea4cups`](http://www.pykota.com/software/tea4cups) which sounds like you could implement a prehook to your script which would do the printing. You could then have this print cancel out and not actually go to a real printer via cups, allowing your script to do the printing instead.

*excerpt*

> #### The possibilities are endless :
>
> - Send the same job to several printers at the same time, which is not possible with CUPS.
> - Automate the PDF archiving of all print jobs.
> - Forbid duplicate print jobs (a simple example is shown in the sample configuration file)
> - Create a print accounting solution in 15 minutes ( YES, THIS IS FOR REAL )
> - etc...

Tea4cups provides the following facilitates:

> #### Tea4CUPS provides three ways to launch commands :
>
> - filters : A filter can modify the input datas before they are sent to the printer or made available to the pre and post hooks defined
>     below. Currently a single filter can be defined per print queue.
> - prehooks : these are guaranteed to be launched before the print job is sent to the real printer. Any prehook which exits -1 can cancel the
>     print job. Any number of prehooks can be defined for a particular
>     print queue.
> - posthooks : these are guaranteed to be launched after the print job has been sent to the real printer, unless the job was previously
>     cancelled by a prehook. Any number of posthooks can be defined for a
>     particular print queue.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add this script as a virtual printer that can be selected
>   from the GUI?

To ad a virtual printer, just edit your `/etc/printcap`. This is not very easy, because the syntax of  [PRINTCAP](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/5/PRINTCAP/) need getting used to.

An example how to do it is showed here [PDF Service with Samba](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue72/bright.html):

```
# /etc/printcap
# PDF Service entry

lp|pdf|PDF Printer:\
        :lp=/dev/null:sh:\
        :sd=/var/spool/lpd/pdf:\
        :af=/var/spool/lpd/pdf/acct:\
        :mx#0:sh:\
        :if=/usr/bin/smbprint:
```

Here the `/usr/bin/smbprint` script is used as a print filter. The printer itself is `/dev/null`.

Perhaps you'll need to install `cups-bsd`, but its often the default config.

Comment: Note that `printcap` is the configuration file for BSD lpr or lprNG, not for CUPS which is the de facto standard nowadays, and is the standard on Mint.

Comment: Therefore I mentioned the `cups-bsd` package, which is also available on Mint, by default installed and also well supported. `cups-bsd` is not lprng! It is only a wrapper, that provides the functionality of BSD printing for Cups in order to support applications which use `lpr` for printing (i.e. xpdf).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I wanted to do the same thing and I did not find any other solution.

I'll write here how i solved it , maybe others will find the solution useful.

- made a filter for cups to catch the file to be printed
- made a backend to print the file
- made a nice and easy installer.

source code is on github:
https://github.com/dentys03/manual_duplex_linux

It should work on any HP printer. Easily adapted for other printers, i guess.